# Show that $f(a+h)=f(a) + hf'(a+t_{h}h)$ and $\lim_{h \to 0} t_{h} = 1/2$

Tags: limits, analysis, functions

Let $f$ be a function of $C^{2}$ in an interval of the form $[a-h,a+h]$ where $h>0$.
Show that if $f''(a)\ne0$ then there exists $t_{h} \in [-1,1]$ such that $$f(a+h)=f(a) + hf'(a+t_{h}h) \quad, \quad
 \lim_{h \to 0} t_{h} = 1/2$$
The first equality is easy using generalized Rolle's theorem, the limit however is confusing : it seems like it should tend to $0$ since that would give us the definition of the derivative at $a$ ie : $\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}= f'(a)$, 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "Let $f$ be a function of $C^2$ near a point $a$ with a radius $h$" makes no sense. A function cannot be near a point $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and how does a point have a radius? You should also mention the domain and codomain of $f$, since without them a function cannot be defined. That being said, my hint is to make use of the second derivative. $C^2$ and $f''(a)\not=0$ are not just there for show.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant it's of class $C^{2}$ in an interval of the form $[a-h,a+h]$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $f'$ is $C^1$, we have the Taylor expansion for $0 \le x \le h$:

$$f'(a+x)=f'(a)+xf''(a)  +o(x)\,.$$
Taking $x=t_h h$ we infer
$$f'(a+t_h h)=f'(a)+t_h hf''(a)+ o(h)\,.$$
Using this in the formula that defined $t_h$ gives
$$f(a+h)=f(a) + hf'(a+t_{h}h)= f(a)+hf'(a)+t_h h^2f''(a)+o(h^2)\,.$$
Now comparing this to the second order Taylor expansion of $f$:
$$f(a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+h^2f''(a)/2+o(h^2)$$
yields (since $f''(a) \ne 0$) that $t_h h^2=h^2/2+o(h^2)$, so  $t_h-1/2 \to 0$ as $ h \to 0$.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Comment: What a neat and clear answer, thank you very much!